# GDPR - A mobile App that allows user to store media do we have to option user consent?

Tags: gdpr

I have a few doubts about GDPR law. If we are a mobile app, that allows user to store data inside our application like photos, videos, notes. etc., then do we have to get user consent or anything related to GDPR?

Example: a vault app.

Also, if the user is storing the data in our app, but the data is not encrypted, then do I need to encrypt data even if are aren't subject to GDPR?

The data is stored locally on the user's phone and it's not uploaded to server.
It's like a private gallery application which is password-protected. The user can move photos.

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what processing *you* do. If you supply a vault app that stores data on the user's device and only the user has access to this data, *you* are not processing personal data, so the GDPR does not apply to the app.

Comment: Yes we are not processing the data we only store the data for the user and apart from the user no one else has the access to it. Also, the data stored is not encrypted so does the GDPR applies as to we have to encrypt the data or anything like that ?

Comment: @FreeRadical I think that point on processing is debatable - under GDPR, storing data IS processing it. see my answer

Comment: @FreeRadical sorry, I was still writing it up! I take your point, but he said "If we are a mobile app" - I would take that to mean his company is, at the very least, gathering, storing and erasing data, which counts even if performed locally and not transmitted to the company themselves, I believe.

Comment: @David. I know that storing is processing (as per GDPR Article 4 definition 2). But whether this use case falls under GDPR hinges  on *who* processes the data. That is not clear in this question. It is a mistake to think, as you seem to do, that just because storing is processing, it falls under the GDPR. This question is IMHO too poorly written to be answerable.

Comment: @FreeRadical I agree the question is both poorly written and impossible to answer fully, though I thought it worth at least worth a shot - i'll update with more detail if we get a response. I do wonder what you mean about who processing the data is unclear though? As he has advised he has a mobile app that stores the data - other than the apps legal owner, be it company or individual who could be the processor of this data? Unless you mean if he is outside the EU and not processing EU citizen data

Comment: @David. The answer to a "who"-question must be some human entity, not some computer application.The "app" can by its very nature not be the controller of this personal data. The apps legal owner can't be controller either, *unless* the apps legal owner controls the data (that follows from the GDPR defintion of "controller"). IBM is not the *controller* of personal data processed by IBM's customers.

Comment: @FreeRadical Ah, I understand you now! I think there's a lot of room for argument, and it will be interesting to see what the courts make of it if a case comes up, but I would argue that unlike a PC (which enforces the 'means' no specific 'purpose') a vault app comes with both a specific means and purpose, set by the developer.

Comment: Or to put it another way: I see IBM more like a pen maker, who can't be held accountable for what you write, even if, for example, you write instructions on bomb-making. But I see an app designer more like a publisher, who already set a purpose and would be in trouble for publishing a pamphlet on the same, regardless of if the reader (user) made one or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "we store the data". Is the data uploaded to your servers? In that case you better encrypt it and make sure it cannot get stolen etc. Why are you doing this? If you mean "our app stores the data on the user's device" then you should say that.

Comment: @David I can sort of see where you are coming from, but you seem to be making a distinction between data processed on a PC (e.g. by a spreadsheet or accounting program) and data processed on a mobile phone by an app. But in both cases it is the user's equipment running a program as instructed by the user. So I don't think your distinction is real. Perhaps this would be better asked as a Question on this site.

Comment: @Frank: can you clarify exactly what data gets taken off the user's device and stored/processed by you? Is the "vault" storage located on the user's device, or on storage devices controlled by you?

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming the data is only stored on the users's device**, (as mentioned in a comment), the GDPR does not apply to the developer of an application.

It could however apply to the user who uses the application. But the question seems to indicate it will be for private use only, the exception in [Art. 2 (2)(c) GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-2-gdpr/) would apply.

> 2. This Regulation does not apply to the processing of personal data:
>
>    (c)   by a natural person in the course of a purely personal or household activity;

If the GDPR would apply, for example because it is used by a company storing photos of customers, it would be the responsibility of the user to comply with the GDPR. If the application is not GDPR-compliant, the user would have to stop using the application.

Answer (score 1):

> if the user is storing the data in our app but the data is not encrypted then do I need to encrypt data even if we do not fall in GDPR?

This reply assumes that you are doing some of the processing and/or storage, as opposed to leaving it all on the user's device.

The GDPR does not directly mandate encryption. Article 32(2) says:

> In assessing the appropriate level of security account shall be taken in particular of the risks that are presented by processing, in particular from accidental or unlawful destruction, loss, alteration, unauthorised disclosure of, or access to personal data transmitted, stored or otherwise processed.

So you need to think about how sensitive the data is likely to be. Then design your data processing and management practices (e.g. which employees have access, what procedures must they follow) accordingly.

So the upshot of all this is, no you don't *have* to encrypt the user's files, but doing so might well be a good idea.